# How can I open a file within the above dir in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am doing a script which opens a file(json) and then do something with it, I am having an issue as the interpreter cannot find the route and actually the route I get when I print it out on screen is quiet weird. I am working on windows if it helps. So this is a bit of code:

```
def playActions(filename):
    # Read the file
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    filepath = os.path.join(script_dir, 'recordings', filename)
    print(filepath)
    with open(filepath, 'r') as jsonfile:
        # parse the json
        data = json.load(jsonfile)
```

and this is this the output:

```
  File "C:/Users/anton/PycharmProjects/videogame_bot/playback.py", line 38, in playActions
    with open(filepath, 'r') as jsonfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\anton\\PycharmProjects\\videogame_bot\\recordings\\actions_test_2020-07-29.json'
C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\videogame_bot
C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\videogame_bot\recordings\actions_test_2020-07-29.json
```

The thing is that when I print  filepath, the result on screen looks fine, I do not know what I am missing though. The folder herarchy is as you can see

[image]

Comment: Can you change `script_dir` to `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`? What does that give you?

Comment: I tried that, I get this:                                                                                                 
 ```                                                                                                                            
with open(filepath, 'r') as jsonfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\anton\\PycharmProjects\\videogame_bot\\recordings\\actions_test_2020-07-29.json'                                                                                                                                
  ````

Comment: I really cannot figure out the mistake...

Comment: Can you try run(Win+R) -> notepad "C:\Users\anton\PycharmProjects\videogame_bot\recordings\actions_test_2020-07-29.json"

Comment: Its possible that the characters are a bit different than you think. You could crack open the shell and `glob.glob('C:\\Users\\anton\\PycharmProjects\\videogame_bot\\recordings\\*.json')` and compare the returned name to "actions_test_2020-07-29.json". Maybe you have a different unicode underscore or dash than you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get absolute path of file and then get directory. In your sample code you get relative path and file can not be found.

Try to modify you code like this

```
import os
import json

def playActions(filename):
    # Get absolute path of file
    full_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    # Extract directory from the path
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(full_path)
    filepath = os.path.join(script_dir, 'recordings', filename)
    print(filepath)
    with open(filepath, 'r') as jsonfile:
        # parse the json
        data = json.load(jsonfile)
```

It works for me, but unfortunately i have no Windows PC, i run this code on OS X.

Comment: I get the same... It was working a while ago, hahaha I dunno what I did

Comment: Weird. But I noticed a bit strange thing in your screenshot, may be you have space between test_ and 2020-07-29 ?

Comment: OMG you are right that was it I should have mistyped it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `__file__` is usually absolute and judging from the error message it is so in that case.